# Intent : Direct binding Activity to BroadcastReceiver without service?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

First of all I wanted to give codes here but the codes are way to long, it can be found here

*http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-and-scheduling-alarms-in-android/*

The codes in the article doesn't create service.

As per my understanding, *`BroadcastReceiver`* is used to serve an activity based on its corresponding *Service* ( via an intent ).

Normally we would declare such :

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CustomeService.class);
   startService(serviceIntent);
   registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
```

where *`mReceiver`* will be something like :

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       }
}
```

But there's something confusing me in AlarmManager class in the example that I shared by the link :

```
intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);  
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(  
                    this.getApplicationContext(), 280192, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);  
            alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);  
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + (i * 1000), 10000  
                    , pendingIntent);
```

The line that is confusing me is this :

*`intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);`*

the type of this `MyBroadcastReceiver.class` is *`BroadcastReceiver`* itself, and not *`Service.`*

So where's the *Service* that this *`MyBroadcastReceiver.class`* received broadcast from then?

Does *BroadcastReceiver* somehow create its own service?

Comment: hmm, what actually do you want to achieve? (i know i repeat that question)

Comment: I mean where's the service that this MyBroadcastReceiver receive broadcast from? I'm sorry if not being clear enough, this is a learning android in 24 hours for me where taking a rest is for weak. My head is tired & full of confusion right now, if it's still not clear please just tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the type of this MyBroadcastReceiver.class is BroadcastReceiver itself, and not Service

Correct. It is being used with `PendingIntent.`getBroadcast()`, not`getService()`.

> So where's the Service that this MyBroadcastReceiver.class received broadcast from then?

Few broadcasts are sent by some `Service`, though that is certainly possible. In this case, the broadcast is being sent from a system process, as part of sending the `PendingIntent`, when the alarm time comes around.

> Does BroadcastReceiver somehow create its own service?

I am not sure what you mean by "create" here. A `BroadcastReceiver` may delegate its work to a `Service`. That is a common pattern with `AlarmManager`: have the alarms trigger a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, which in turn delegates work to an `IntentService`. In that case, the reason for the indirection stems from the way that `AlarmManager` works with `WakeLocks`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation I hope I could upvote many times.